# Change row colour if all checkboxes checked?

Tags: jquery

This topic has been covered in detail for only 1 tickbox - my problem is I need to highlight the table row if none of the tickboxes are ticked with the colour red or white is at least one is ticked. So if none are ticked highlight red but if at least one is ticked then highlight white. I have this code :

```
$("input:checkbox").live("change", function (event) {
    $("tr checkbox").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass('white');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('white');
        }
    });
});
```

The html is basically just a table row with two pieces of data and 7 tickboxes - if none our ticked then highlight red but if at least 1 is ticked then highlight white.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I found that because I swapped from .live() to .on() and my tickboxes were being loaded dynamically. I had to bind the function to a non-dynamic element this is the code that I used in the end :

```
$("#emaillistbox").on("change","input:checkbox", function (event) {
var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
if($tr.find("input:checked").length > 0)
{
    $tr.removeClass('red').addClass('white');
}else {
    $tr.removeClass('white').addClass('red');
}
});
```

`emaillistbox` is the name of the div in which my dynamic content is loaded.

Comment: You state you want the class added if all are ticked, then if only 1 is ticked. Can you please clarify exactly which of these cases is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do something like this:**

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function (event) {
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    if($tr.find("input:checked").length > 0)
    {
        $tr.removeClass('red').addClass('white');
    }else {
        $tr.removeClass('white').addClass('red');
    }
});
```

**[See this working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kDtjP/)**

**Updated**

To make it work with dynamic content use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("input:checkbox", "change", function (event) { });
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NJPw4/)**

Comment: that's great how would I make it work for dynamic content? ie if those tick boxes were loaded via ajax?

Comment: Thanks for your help I solved it by binding the function to my non dynamic div in the end, but I see your way works too.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to do this way:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function (event) {
   $("tr input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
       if ($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length >= $("input[type='checkbox']").length) {
          $(this).closest('tr').addClass('white');
       } else {
          $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('white');
       }
    });
});
```

try to check the length of the `:checked` if that is equal to the length of the checkboxes length only then  apply css class to the parent `tr`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you can check to see if there are any unchecked boxes in the row to remove the `each` loop, secondly, you should make the `tr` relative to the clicked checkbox, finally, use `on` instead of `live` as it's deprecated. Try this:

```
$("input:checkbox").on('change', function (event) {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    if ($(':checkbox', $tr).not(':checked').length) {
        // not all checked
        $tr.removeClass('white');
    }
    else {
        // all checked in row
        $tr.addClass('white');
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DXDkj/)

Comment: Maybe use `:not()` function in place of compare numbers of checked checkboxes and total of checkboxes. Just check if the length of checkboxes-not-checked is greater than 0.

Comment: @JBRTRND good point, that is a more elegant method, amended - thanks.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan .on() isn't working I think because of my ajax call - which is what loads in the tickbox form. What am I doing wrong? The jquery functions work on the same page but not on anything not on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

try to use a flag variable to do this.and `.live()` is deprecated.try to use **.on()**

```
$(document).on("change","input:checkbox", function (event) {
   var flag = true;
    $("tr checkbox").each(function () {
        if (!$(this).attr('checked')) 
           flag = false;

    });

    if(flag == true)
         $(this).closest('tr').addClass('white');
    else
          $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('white');

});
```

Comment: Flag will be true if only the last checkbox is checked, initialize it at true then control only if one checkbox isn't checked.

Comment: Thank you - is it the same function if I use .on() ? Apart from changing .live() to .on() ofcourse.

Comment: @PSR with .on() the function doesn't fire when I tick a box? It does with .live() though - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: which version you are using

Comment: None - first place checked

Comment: if u have some time can u create js fiddle link

Comment: @PSR the checkboxes are being loaded from an ajax call - could that cause the function not to fire>?

Comment: @PSR Thank you - now that I'm using .on() my functions aren't firing. I'm guessing this is down to the fact that the functions are on the main page and the tickbox form is loaded in via ajax. I'm using `$(document).ready(function(){` is that not correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").live("change", function (event) {
  if ($(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0) {
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('white');
  } else {
    $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('white');
  }
}
```

Comment: although it's used by OP, live function is deprecated

Comment: @Bartdude: This solution will surely work for ch3my. Using `on` doesn't have to, because it was introduced not so long ago.

Comment: Note this will add the class if 1 checkbox is checked, OP wants it to happen if ALL checkboxes are checked.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: "So if none are ticked highlight red but if at least one is ticked then highlight white."

Comment: @LukLed Hmm seems OP is confused about what he wants, the sentence directly before that is: `my problem is I need to highlight the table row if all the checkboxes on that row are ticked`.

Comment: LukLed > the fact something is not deprecated for long doesn't mean you should use it for new dev, only you're not in an emergency to update your existing codebase. your answer would be better with that single change

Answer (score 1):

You should use some boolean flags to control the states

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function (event) {
    var some = false;
    var all = true;
    var none = true;
    $("tr checkbox").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            some = true; 
            none = false;
        } else {
            all = false; 
        }
    });
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    row.removeClass('green').removeClass('red').removeClass('white')
    if (all)
      row.addClass('green')
    elseif (none)
      row.addClass('red')
    elseif (some)
      row.addClass('white')
});
```

Hope this helps